# How to read tensorflow .pb model?

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I have one tensorflow segmentation model, I have successfully converted it to the .pb file.

The issue is this .pb file (protocol buffer) doesn't have the input tensor that I usually use to feed the data (input image). So, I don't know how to use the .pb file to perform an image segmentation.

I appreciate any help that I can get!

Comment: It depends on how you converted your data to the .pb file. Did you save your model as a SavedModel? Or did you use TFRecords? What function did you use to create the .pb file?

Comment: I used the function "frozen_graph_def.SerializeToString()" to convert the model into .pb file from the checkpoint. I use the tfrecords as an input to train my model but I want to use the .jpg image for the testing.

Comment: do you have an example ? how do i load the pb file then run the architecture ? where is my architecture ?